# "make something adjective" or "make adjective something"?

Tags: word-order

Which form is correct?

> make + something + adjective

or

> make + adjective + something

For instance:

> I want to make it clear.

or

> I want to make clear it.

Another example (from the paper [GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf)):

> We analyze and
>   **make explicit the model properties** needed
>   for such regularities to emerge in word
>   vectors

Is the last usage correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**make something clear** is an example of a [phrasal verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/phrasal-verbs) - a verb plus a particle p. p is normally an adverb or preposition, but in this case it's an adjective. Some phrasal verbs can exist in two patterns: the usual pattern is N+V+N+p but sometimes the pattern is  N+V+p+N. Examples might be:

> I looked his name up
>   I looked up his name.

The usual form is **make *something* clear**, and this is used when *something* is just a few words. If *something* is a complex noun phrase, we get uncomfortable about the distance between **make** and **clear**, especially if the noun phrase could cause misleading parsing, for example **make the difference...**, so we move **make clear** together and put the noun phrase at the end.

For personal pronouns like **it**, the first form is always used and a short noun phrase like the example below is probably still OK using the first form.

> ...make **the reason for his actions** clear.

It has to get to something like the two examples below before we start to favour the at-the-end approach.

> make **the difference between right and wrong** clear.
>  
>   make clear **the difference between right and wrong**.

Looking at the second example that you quoted, both **analyze** and **make explicit** apply to the noun phrase (highlighted), so the sentence would not make sense if the noun phrase were in the middle:

> We analyze and make explicit **the model properties needed for such regularities to emerge in word vectors**

Note also that the noun phrase is a lot more complex than you indicated, so even without the **analyze and** complication, the at-the-end approach would not only  be grammatically correct, but would be the preferred option. Here is a real example:

> In this study, we make a simplified mathematical model for the ladder of van der Pol oscillators coupled by inductors in order to make clear **the mechanism of the generation of the wave-motion**. [Proceedings of the IEEE](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=NlVaXZZbJgQC&pg=PA105&dq=%22make%20clear%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuPTNzMnSAhUGnRoKHZvLD-8Q6AEIPDAH#v=onepage&q=%22make%20clear%20the%22&f=false)

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20it%20clear%2C%20make%20clear%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20it%20clear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20clear%20the%3B%2Cc0) shows that **make it clear** is not so far ahead of **make clear the...** in terms of frequency of use in writing. You can look at the actual instances to see further examples of noun phrase usages.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. In terms of clarity, for sure you are correct, but I want to know whether it is correct in terms of grammar or not.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct: indeed, for your final sentence it is the only pattern that could work, for the reasons that I have explained. I have added some more explanation and a reference.